# Equal ordinate zeros for the Riemann-zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Write $\rho=\beta + i\gamma$ and $\rho'=\beta'+i\gamma'$ for two distinct non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta-function. Is it known that $\gamma\neq\gamma'$? That is, does a proof exist that two zeros can't have the same ordinate?

Certainly, it is true under the Riemann hypothesis but I'm curious as for whether this is true unconditionally.

EDIT: To clarify, by distinct I mean that $\rho\neq\rho'$ so that we are not considering any matters relating to multiplicity. Also, as mentioned in the comments one should assume $\beta,\:\beta'\geq\frac{1}{2}$ as to avoid triviality.

Comment: It is *not* known to be true under the Riemann Hypothesis. Whether the nontrivial zeros are simple is a wide open problem! See e.g. [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/59770).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm interested in the case where the zeros are distinct (rather than worrying about issues of multiplicity). I've updated the question for clarity

Comment: If a non-trivial zero is not on the critical line, then its reflection across the critical line is also a zero. I imagine that's also too trivial for your question :) If you exclude that and only consider $\beta \ge 1/2$ then I don't know.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @echinodermata, I'll update the question as to avoid this triviality

Comment: Seems obvious that no two pairs of zeros have the same ordinate, but I don't think this is proven.